# How to get rollup to include a dependency from another package in a lerna monorepo in its transpilation (TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollup, lerna

I created a minimal example to show the question I have: [Github repo](https://github.com/goepi/lru-test).

I have a lerna monorepo with two npm packages in the `packages` folder, the packages are called:

**utils**: exports a function:

```
export const add = (a:number, b: number) => a + b
```

**component-library:**: exports one simple functional React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { add } from '@project/utils';

export const MyComponent = () => <div>{add(2, 2)}</div>;
```

The root of the monorepo has a `tsconfig.json`, which defines a `paths` key to map any imports of the form `@project/*` to the packages.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@project/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["**/build/**"]
}
```

Each package has a `rollup.config.js`, both essentially identical (though we're only going to use the one in the `component-library` package here):

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        dir: './build',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        commonjs(),
        typescript({ tsconfig: '../../tsconfig.json'}),
    ]
};
```

Therefore, they both use the paths defined in the root `tsconfig.json`, and they use a plugin for transpiling Typescript.

`component-library` imports a function from `@project/utils` called `add(a,b)`.

My goal is to create a build of this library (using `rollup`), without having to build the `utils` package first. In other words, I want to build `component-library` resolving imports from `utils` to the source code of `utils`, not the build folder in the symlinked package in `node_modules` (ie, not using the symlinks created by lerna).

I almost achieve this, except that when I run the build script in `component-library`, I get an error:

> src/index.tsx → ./build... [!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you
>   need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
>   ..\utils\src\index.ts (1:21) 1: export const add = (a:number, b:
>   number) => a + b
>                           ^

The way I understand this, it means that the resolution of the import works fine, but rollup is not transpiling the TS file coming from an external dependency.

**How do I tell rollup to include the file from utils in the transpilation through rollup?**

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784292/why-cant-i-import-a-ts-file-of-a-package-found-in-node-modules-using-rollup-an

Comment: Did you fix this @evianpring?

Comment: A small thing, but looking at your Rollup setup and comparing to mine, there's one thing missing. I put `nodeResolve({ extensions, }),` first, inside `plugins[]`, above `commonjs(),`. The `extensions` is a string array like `const extensions = [".js", ".json", ".node", ".ts", ".tsx"];`. Try this. The import is `import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really the issue

> The way I understand this, it means that the resolution of the import works fine, but rollup is not transpiling the TS file coming from an external dependency.

You can run Babel from `@rollup/plugin-babel` and transpile ts files with Babel directly. Babel will go over files in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

For a monorepo, many if not all packages will be hoisted. So get the resolving to look higher. Try using the nodeResolve option:

```
{
    rootDir: path.join(process.cwd(), '..')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a working monorepo like the on you described using `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` and `rollup-plugin-typescript2`. The component library just serves out react components which can be installed with npm. I got it working using esm as the output type and omitting the commonjs() step in plugins.

The plugins section looks something like this:

```
plugins: [
  resolve(),
  typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
],
```